# Spotify API - Location

Tags: spotify

I am trying to use "api/location" as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/location-location.html) but for some reason that's always failing with error `code 0`, type `transient`, which is not really helpful. Any ideas.

```
var loc = location.query();  

loc.load(['latitude']).done(function(loc) {
    console.log("Lat:" + loc.latitude); 
}).fail(function(track, error){
  console.log(error); 
});
```

Also, it would help if anyone can explain how the location is retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20196967/1036087 the location API never actually worked and they're going to remove the documentation on it.