# Spotify api - using location data

Tags: spotify

Does the spotify api allow the option to pull down data related to location?

1. Most popular genre of music in a location
2. Most popular artist in your area
3. Most popular band in your area

https://developer.spotify.com/spotify-echo-nest-api/

^ I was going to apply for an account with the echo nest - to start testing these types of responses - but they have made some changes..

an example --

```
http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/profile?api_key={echonest_api_key}&id=spotify:artist:5l8VQNuIg0turYE1VtM9zV&format=json&bucket=artist_location
```

//jsfiddle with a basic api in place
http://jsfiddle.net/0u0v7e1b/971/

```
searchAlbums("bowie");

    function fetchTracks (albumId, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/' + albumId,
            success: function (response) {
                callback(response);
            }
        });
    };

    function searchAlbums(query) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search',
            data: {
                q: query,
                type: 'album'
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $.each(data.albums.items, function(k, v) {
                    console.log("results-->", v);
                    $("#album").append('<li><div>Name:: '+v.name+'</div></li>');
                });
            }
        });
    };
```

--having issues trying to get authetnication to work for different queries.

```
var url = "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token";
            url += "?client_id=" + this.clientId;
            url += "&client_secret=" + this.clientSecret;
            url += "&grant_type=authorization_code";
            url += "&redirect_uri=" + this.redirectUrl;
            url += "&code=" + this.code;

            this.getJson(url, function(data) {
              //console.log("authorize",data);
            })
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606677/spotify-api-location

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196869/what-methods-can-i-use-for-geolocation-through-a-spotify-app/20196967#20196967